# To which edition of Monopoly would this Monopoly board belong?

Tags: monopoly

[image: Picture of the Monopoly board]
To which edition of Monopoly would this board belong?

Source : Facebook page for Monopoly collectors.

Comment: Are you sure it's a commercially available edition and not someones art project?  All the ones I see online have trademark icons on the board?   The place names appear to be the Atlantic City version rather than a specify themed version.  The art also appear hand drawn rather than commercially printed.  It is also missing the 'just visiting' space next to where 'in jail' would be.

Comment: @StartPlayer It's not missing the just visiting space, it's just very faded. You can see the text just beneath the image of the person in jail.

Comment: @Draken ah yes didn't see that as it was very faint.  Again that makes me think this is a art project for Atlantic City rather than a commercially available edition but someone may well know better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's concept art

From [an ebay description](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1976-MONOPOLY-Board-Game-NEIMAN-MARCUS-Concept-Art-Drawing-Prototype-w-Sketches/333575238460):

> an Original Monopoly Neiman Marcus Concept / Prototype Artwork from 1976. This was purchased from a Neiman Marcus marketing executives estate sale, whom worked at the company in the late 60’s & 1970’s.